# Using each() to loop over a specific parent's children

Tags: jquery

I have the following HTML structure:

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child">
    </div>
    <div class="child">
    </div>
    <div class="child">
    </div>
</div>
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child">
    </div>
    <div class="child">
    </div>
</div>
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child">
    </div>
    <div class="child">
    </div>
    <div class="child">
    </div>
    <div class="child">
    </div>
</div>
```

And my question is, during an `each()` loop of the parents, how can I then loop over that specific parent's children? This is the (unworking) code I have so far.

```
var parents = $('div.parent');
var children = $('div.child');

$(parents).each(function(index, value) {
    // do something
    $(children, parents + index).each(function() {
        //do something else
    });
});
```

The alternative option I suppose is to set the children variable within that first `each()`, but again I'm unsure how to do that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is partly because you're selecting `div.child` globally in the `children` variable, and partly because you're trying to append an integer value (`index`) with a jQuery object (`parents`), which will not work.

To achieve what you require you need to get the `children()` of the current `.parent` element in the loop, which can be done by using the `this` keyword. Try this:

```js
var $parents = $('div.parent');

$parents.each(function() {
  $(this).children().each(function() {
    console.log($(this).text());
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">A-1</div>
  <div class="child">A-2</div>
  <div class="child">A-3</div>
</div>
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">B-1</div>
  <div class="child">B-2</div>
</div>
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">B-1</div>
  <div class="child">B-2</div>
  <div class="child">B-3</div>
  <div class="child">B-4</div>
</div>
```

Comment: maybe could be posible make it with $(this).children('.child').each(function() ... because children is faster than find in case that child got another html tags.